Linear $3\times3$ system of differential equations with multiple eigenvectors
Find a solution basis of $$y'=\left( \begin{matrix}-1&-4&2\\2&5&-1\\2&2&2\\ \end{matrix} \right)y.$$
Eigenvalues are $\lambda=0, 3$ (3 is a double root)
For $\lambda=0$, an eigenvector is $[-2, 1, 1]^T$ and I obtained the corresponding solution.
$$\begin{align} 
y_1=-2c_1\\ 
y_2=c_1\\ 
y_3=c_1\\
\end{align}$$
For $\lambda$=3, I obtained the following matrix:
$$\left( \begin{matrix}-4&-4&2\\2&2&-1\\2&2&-1\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
Reduce to:
$$\left( \begin{matrix}0&0&0\\2&2&-1\\0&0&0\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
From this, I find four non-trivial linearly independent eigenvectors, $[1, -1, 0]^T$, $[1, 0, 2]^T$, $[0, 1, 2]^T$, $[1, 1, 4]^T$.  All of those fulfil the  equation $(A-\lambda I)\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$
The solution in the back of the book (Kreyszig's Advanced Engineering Mathematics 8th ed, section 3.3, problem 9):
$$\begin{align} 
y_1=-2c_1+(c_2-c_3)e^{3t}\\ 
y_2=c_1+c_3e^{3t}\\ 
y_3=c_1+2c_2e^{3t}\\
\end{align}$$
Using this method, because 3 is a double root, I was expecting there to be a $C_3te^{3t}$ term in the solution, and I don't know how to work the method otherwise.
Any insight would be appreciated.
BTW, I did check that the solution was correct (I've never seen a wrong answer in Kreyszig anyway).

You cannot have 4 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Furthermore, the dimension of the $\lambda=3$ eigenspace is at most 2 since it is linearly independent from the $\lambda=0$ eigenspace

In linear systems, the consequence of a double root as you propose only eventuates if the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are different. However, if the matrix is diagonizable, no extra factors $t$ will occur.

For the system
$$y'=\left( \begin{matrix}-1&-4&2\\2&5&-1\\2&2&2\\ \end{matrix} \right)y$$
We get the eigenvalues
$$\lambda_{1} = 0, \lambda_{2,3} = 3$$
For the zero eigenvalue, we reduce $(A-\lambda_1 I)\textbf{v_1}= (A-0 I)\textbf{v_1}= \textbf{0}$. The RREF leads to
$$\left( \begin{matrix}1&0&2\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0 \end{matrix} \right) v_{1} = \textbf{0}$$
From this, we can select
$$v_1 = \left( \begin{matrix}-2\\1\\1\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
For the repeated eigenvalue, we reduce $(A-\lambda_2 I)\textbf{v_2}= (A-3 I)\textbf{v_2}= \textbf{0}$ and we are able to find two linearly independent eigenvectors (this is not always true, otherwise, we would be finding generalized eigenvectors and would have the extra $t$ factor you mentioned). The RREF leads to
$$\left( \begin{matrix}1&1 & -\dfrac{1}{2}\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\ \end{matrix} \right) v_{2,3} = \textbf{0}$$
From this, we can select two linearly independent eigenvectos as
$$v_2 = \left( \begin{matrix}1\\0\\2\\ \end{matrix} \right),v_3 = \left( \begin{matrix}-1\\1\\0\\ \end{matrix} \right)$$
Now we can write
$$Y(t) = \left( \begin{matrix}y_1(t)\\y_2(t)\\y_3(t)\\ \end{matrix} \right) = c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}v_1 + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2 + c_3 e^{\lambda_3 t} v_3$$
This results in
$$ Y(t) = c_1 e^{0t} \left( \begin{matrix}-2\\1\\1\\ \end{matrix} \right)+c_2 e^{3t} \left( \begin{matrix}1\\0\\2\\ \end{matrix} \right) + c_3 e^{3t} \left( \begin{matrix}-1\\1\\0\\ \end{matrix} \right) $$

So in this case, because there is more than one linearly independent eigenvector for eigenvalue of 3, the t-term does not come into play.   That is very helpful.  I tried it out using the other two linearly independent eigenvectors, [0, 1, 2]$^T$, [1, 1, 4]$^T$ and ended up with the same answer (well, different, but not linearly independent of the same answer, so effectively the same answer).  Thanks!

Correct, the $t$ does not come into play. They are many matrix examples on this site. Remember, eigenvectors are not unique.
